# Washing machine has sand and leaves in it after someone did a load

Tags: washing-machine

There are leaves and sand in the washing machine, I filled it up with water and flushed out most of it and wiped up the rest with a towel, then did a small load of laundry, now there is more in there, but not as much as the first time. What the heck is going on?

Comment: it probably accumulated itself behind the drum, where you can't reach it; flush it a few more times

Answer (score 1):

Use a shop vacuum to suck out the sand and leaves.